# PHP MySQL double inner join

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have three tables:

**posts**

- id
- post_id
- user_id

**comments**

- id
- post_id
- comment_id
- user_id
- deleted

**replies**

- id
- post_id
- reply_id
- user_id
- deleted

I am trying to get all comments and replies from each `post.post_id` with `post.user_id=x`.

I tried:

```
    SELECT *
    FROM posts AS p
    INNER JOIN comments as c
    ON c.comment_id=p.post_id
    INNER JOIN replies as r
    ON r.reply_id=p.post_id
    WHERE
    p.user_id='x'
```

which returns 0...

---

The solution was

```
SELECT *
FROM POSTS A
LEFT JOIN COMMENTS B ON A.POST_ID=B.COMMENT_ID
LEFT JOIN REPLIES C ON A.POST_ID=C.REPLY_ID
WHERE A.USER_ID='X'
```

So if I add a deleted column on the *comments* and *replies* tables, how can I check if the comment or reply I am getting is not deleted?

I tried adding after `A.USER_ID='X' && B.deleted='0' && C.deleted='0'`

But it returns 0.

Comment: change the * to specific fields it will make more sense to you

Comment: i am trying to get the total rows of this query... so if i wanna get some columns i should add them instead of * in order to make i work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're missing a key relationship in your model.  You need to have a column in replies and comments for post_id, and then join the tables on post_id.

Once you've made this change, then your query would look like this:

```
SELECT c.*, r.* 
FROM posts p
INNER JOIN comments c ON p.id=c.post_id
INNER JOIN replies r ON p.id=r.post_id
WHERE p.user_id=$user_id
```

Comment: if i add 2 columns on comments and replies as deleted, how can i check if the comment or reply is deleted or not? 0 is not deleted and 1 is deleted... i tried adding && c.deleted='0' && r.deleted='0' in the where clause but i get 0 as return

Comment: @fxuser - regarding additional WHERE criteria, don't use `&&`, use `AND`

Answer (score 2):

Try using left joins instead of inner joins. This will ensure that all rows from the POSTS table matching the WHERE criteria are present.

```
SELECT *
FROM POSTS A
LEFT JOIN COMMENTS B ON A.POST_ID=B.COMMENT_ID
LEFT JOIN REPLIES C ON A.POST_ID=C.REPLY_ID
WHERE A.USER_ID='X'
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, the **post_id** is missing from all tables. Too many ids.

Change your table so the relationships are obvious, and then you can pull the data out quite easily.